# Ranking a table of records by year in Oracle sql

Tags: oracle, rank, dense-rank

I have a table of records in a Oracle DBA which has the two columns

```
Employee Id  and year
12343.           2016
12343.           2017
12343.           2018
12343.           2019
```

I want to rank this with 2019 having rank 3 ,2018 rank 2 and 2107 as rank 1.i only need three years of data for the employee.(2019,2018,2017)..all others should be exuded 
I achieved this by using dense rank.

Where I need help is on a  requirement if the max year of the employee is 2018 then the rank should be 3 and for 2017 should be 2 .for e.g

```
Emoyee I'd.     Year.  Rank
2000.            2017.  2
2000.            2018.  3
```

Similarly if another employee max year is 2017 he should have rank 3

So basically all latest year for that employeee should start with 3.

Any help to achieve this uisng Oracle sql will be handy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible that an employee would have years 2017 and 2019, but not 2018? If so, ok, 2019 will have rank 3. What rank should 2017 have in that case?

Comment: Hi ,No year will be in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
with
  test_data (employee, yr) as (
    select 1001, 2015 from dual union all
    select 1001, 2016 from dual union all
    select 1001, 2017 from dual union all
    select 1001, 2018 from dual union all
    select 1001, 2019 from dual union all
    select 1003, 2018 from dual union all
    select 1003, 2019 from dual union all
    select 1003, 2020 from dual union all
    select 1008, 2015 from dual union all
    select 1008, 2016 from dual union all
    select 1008, 2017 from dual
  )
select employee, yr, 
       4 - rank() over (partition by employee order by yr desc) as rnk
from   test_data
where  yr in (2017, 2018, 2019)
order  by employee, yr desc    --   or whatever is needed
;

  EMPLOYEE         YR        RNK
---------- ---------- ----------
      1001       2019          3
      1001       2018          2
      1001       2017          1
      1003       2019          3
      1003       2018          2
      1008       2017          3
```

Note that the `with` clause is not part of the solution; I included it there to generate test data. Remove it, and use your actual table and column names.

Comment: Perfect,it served my purpose...thanks mathguy...i removed hardcoing of the years and used sysdate to extract the year and used it to get the last three years..thanks a million.